# How to read a file content using shell script

Tags: shell

```
cat file.txt 
(
    while read line
    do
        initial_time=`head -n 1 $line| sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]      [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
       initial_time_sec=`date -d "$initial_time" +%s`
    done
)
```

I want to take the date from every line , if it is less than 60 days I have to store it   in variable

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line ; do
  initial_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
  initial_time_sec=`date -d "$initial_time" +%s`
  now=`date +%s`
  pass_time=`expr $now - $initial_time_sec`
  limit_time=$((60 * 24 * 60))
  if [[ $pass_time -lt $limit_time ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                         
    echo $line
  fi  
done <data
```

Comment: How to compare the date which is less than 60 days while file reading

Comment: @user3165241 Could you please give some examples of your file contents? :) Is it a log file?

Comment: 2013-11-06 15:53:49 HB Thread alive (1)
    2013-11-07 15:53:49 heartBeatCallback starting fireHeartBeat
    2013-11-08 15:53:50 refreshPollingTime END
    2013-11-07 15:53:50 heartBeatCallback testing childpid
    2013-11-07 15:53:50 heartBeatCallback end
    2013-11-07 15:53:50 HB end callback call
    2014-01-05 16:03:51 HB Thread alive (1)

Comment: Thanks I will implement and check it.

Comment: @user3165241 But the example you provide has mutils time, which do you want?